# JFileChooser confusion

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I have to write a program that essentially makes a report card, but it cannot do so until until it reads in a file either through command line arguments or by the user picking one from their browser, which means I need to use JFileChooser. I have the GUI set-up for the JFileChooser but that's all I can figure out. The dialog window opens when I click open but after picking a file the window I created (GUI) does not close. Also the program runs through all of my other methods before a file is even loaded causing other problems. I tried using a do-while loop but it just runs through the loop before I can ever open a file.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MP1 extends JFrame implements java.awt.event.ActionListener{
static StudentAssignments geen165 = new StudentAssignments();
static boolean fileReady = false;
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public static void main(String [] args) {

    do{
        if(args.length == 0 || args[0].isEmpty()){//reads in input from file
                                                  //select
           MP1 doIt = new MP1();
           doIt.setVisible(true);
        }
        else{
         geen165.readGradeFile(args[0]);//reads in input file from command 
                                        //argument 
        }
    }while(!fileReady);
    //test methods 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, geen165.getGradeReport());

        geen165.addAssignments(3, 98, 100);
        geen165.saveGradeFile("NewGrades.txt");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, geen165.getGradeReport());

        geen165.removeAssignment(0, 2);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, geen165.getGradeReport());
}


//JFile Chooser GUI
public MP1(){
    prepareGui();
}

private void prepareGui(){
    setSize(500,500);

    Container window = getContentPane();
    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    JButton open = new JButton("Open");
    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    JLabel status = new JLabel("You've selected: ");

    //sets file when open is pressed
    open.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(window);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            File fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            status.setText("You've selected: " + fileName.getName());
            geen165.readGradeFile(fileName.getName());
            fileReady=true;
        }
    });
    //exits program if cancel is pressed
    cancel.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        System.exit(1); 
    });
    window.add(open);
    window.add(cancel);
    window.add(status);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE); 
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change 
                        //body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are complicating a simple issue. There is no need for you to build a window and everything only to use JFileChooser. A simple solution that works is

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MP1 extends JFrame  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myFile="";

        if (args.length == 0 || args[0].isEmpty()) {//reads in input from file
            //select
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (returnVal!=JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                myFile = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for playing!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } else {
            myFile = args[0];
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have selected "+myFile+". Go play!");
    }

}
```

Notice that I check whether there is a parameter. If not, I immediately go and execute the JFileChooser. There is no need for overhead.

I removed all your class activity, because I do not have the files.

BTW, I have not tested it, but I believe that your problem comes from your new frame not being modal. Hence, the boolean variable is changed before you can do anything. But that is just an idea.

Comment: Ok, I thought that JFileChooser required a GUI. I'll try this out and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know how JFileChooser works.

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

int optionSelected = fc.showOpenDialog(YourClassName.this);

if (optionSelected == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
     File file = fc.getSelectedFile(); 
     ... // Do what you want with the file
}
```

[JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)